# webassembly - что же это такое?

Tags: webassembly

пытаюсь составить самое общее представление о webassembly.

Я так понимаю - webassembly - это очень грубо код, который понимают браузеры.

Код этот можно писать напрямую, но видимо большинство так никто не делает, аналогично тому, что писать код на просто ассемблере.

- Код написанный на С/С++ можно перевести в webassembly-код с помощью  Emscripten.
- Код написанный на Rust можно перевести в webassembly-код с помощью каких внутренних стандартный команд.

Но, "автоматический" перевод кода из С/С++ в webassembly - возможен только потому, что кто то решил создать такой инструмент Emscripten, если бы его не было, то и возможности переводить С/С++ в webassembly - тоже не было бы, разве, что вручную ? Правильно ?

И такой вопрос: Emscripten переводит в OpenGl в WebGl, который понимают браузеры, но получается, что:

-Во первых: Код OpenGl будет ограничен только возможностями браузерного WebGl ?

-Во вторых: Emscripten переводит код только OpenGl, ни Vulkan, ни Metal - в  webassembly преобразован не будет, только С++ и только OpenGl и то только ограниченное кол-во команд OpenGl, при этому еще и надо знать, какие именно команды OpenGl нельзя использовать, то есть нужно знать хотя бы в общих чертах возможности WebGl. Правильно понимаю ?

PS: Прошу прощения за сумбурные вопросы - я только пытаюсь разобраться в общих чертах.

Comment: На всякий случай — кроме WebGL есть ещё [WebGPU](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=55172), который вроде как похож на Vulkan (хотя и не основан на нём)

Comment: @andreymal, Спасибо. Но, как я понимаю браузеры еще не поддерживают WebGpu - по крайне мере "оффциально" и тем более WebGpu  не поддерживает Emscripten. :(

Comment: @andreymal, кстати тут: https://gpuweb.github.io/gpuweb/ - вообще почему то написано, что WebGPU - "Это не стандарт W3C и не входит в список стандартов W3C."

Comment: Это просто неофициальный черновик, а [официальная версия](https://www.w3.org/TR/webgpu/) вполне входит